# Integrate payment method using paypal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have events and courses for which users can book and do the payment. I have events, courses and booking controllers and views for that. I want my booking model to fetch event details when the user selects events or course details when the user selects the course. How do I modify my paypal_url method model so that I have both event and course details?

Booking.rb

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :course , :optional => true
 belongs_to :event, :optional => true

 serialize :notification_params, Hash
  def paypal_url(return_path)
  values = {
    business: "merchant@gmail.com",
    cmd: "_xclick",
    upload: 1,
    return: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}#{return_path}",
    invoice: id,
    amount: course.course_fee,
    item_name: course.title,
    item_number: course.id,
    quantity: '1',
    notify_url: "#{Rails.application.secrets.app_host}/hook"
  }
  "#{Rails.application.secrets.paypal_host}/cgi-bin/webscr?" + 
  values.to_query
 end
end
```

Comment: I don't think booking model is a good place to construct your paypal url, maybe a paypal service class would be a more correct place to put that code

Comment: @Subash. okay. I didn't know that we have to create a separate class for that. But for now, can you tell me to modify this model.

Comment: can you be more specific with "modify this model", what is it that you want to do ? what things do you want to add to the method ?

Comment: @Subash I want the PayPal method to select event .event_fee , event. title and event.id when the user selects events. i.e I want to add an if condition so that , it selects course_fees when the user selects course and event_fees when the user selects events

Comment: I'm still unclear what is it that you want, do you just want to add `event_fee, title, id` to the values hash?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your values hash,

```
values = {
  ...
  event_fee: event.event_fee,
  title: event.title,
  id: event.id
}
```

I'm not sure if this is what you're after.

you may have to change the key names (`event_fee, title, id`) if they should be something else

Comment: if u dont mind can we discuss in chatroom. so that i can  explain you properly

Comment: Yes. but you need to invite me.

Comment: how can I do that ?

Comment: I have created the group by name Rails. Can you plz join.